# Get a list of passwords/characters from nested for-loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I understand how nested for-loops work, but I don't yet understand how to implement them in Java.  In the code I have, there must be a misplaced curly bracket, or a command out of place.  I have been trying for hours using different configurations to no avail.

I have looked at other examples on SO including some in other programming languages.

The output I am attempting to get in a textbox looks something like this,

ekdk15hY7S

8fk4Wma7Ht

5kkr278nhS

etc.

but all that I am getting is one line in the textbox, instead of the list I want.  I tell the program through the GUI how many passwords I want and how many characters/digits per password.

The code works fine in giving me one password when I comment-out the first for-loop, and add or remove a curly bracket.

Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?  Here is the code:

```
//  numb is how many characters per password.
String numbSTR = spinner1.getValue().toString();
int numb = Integer.parseInt(numbSTR);               

//count is how many passwords do you want.
String countSTR = spinner2.getValue().toString();
int count = Integer.parseInt(countSTR);


//count is how many passwords do you want.
for (int x = 0; x < count; x++ ) {
    String buildPW = "";
    //numb is how many characters per password.               
    for (int y = 0; y < numb; y++ ) {
        Random position = new SecureRandom();
        String digits =  "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";                                                                         
        int index = (int)     (position.nextDouble()*digits.length());
        buildPW += digits.substring(index, index+1);      
    }       

    TextArea1.setText(buildPW + crlf); // put each new password in the textbox.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine. Here is more or less the same version, which works:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     int count = 10;
     int numb = 8;
     for (int x = 0; x < count; x++ ) {
     String buildPW = "";
     for (int y = 0; y < numb; y++ ) {

        String digits =      "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";                                                                         
        int index = (int)     (Math.random()*digits.length());
        buildPW += digits.substring(index, index+1);
      }     

   System.out.println(buildPW);
   }  


  }
}
```

So, what your problem really is you setText on textView. But what you really want is to appendText. So, if you change:

```
 TextArea1.setText(buildPW + crlf);
```

to

```
 TextArea1.appendText(buildPW + crlf);
```

It should work.

SetText, replaces the whole text within the textArea at once. In your case, you set the content of textArea to the latest the greatest password. On the other hand, appendText, appends the given text to the end of text in the textArea. (similar to System.out.println code in above example).

Comment: I see through to the truth!  This worked by changing it to ".appendText" like you said.  It is like adding more data to an already existing text file.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Move the settext and buildPW outside of the loops:

```
// Moved
String buildPW = "";
//count is how many passwords do you want.
for (int x = 0; x < count; x++ ) {
    //numb is how many characters per password.               
    for (int y = 0; y < numb; y++ ) {
        Random position = new SecureRandom();
        String digits =  "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";                                                                         
        int index = (int)     (position.nextDouble()*digits.length());
        buildPW += digits.substring(index, index+1) + crlf;      
    }
} 
// Moved
TextArea1.setText(buildPW); // put each new password in the textbox.
```

Comment: this does not work as there is no crlf at the end of each password. 3 passwords of 8 chars each may look like BCLZRHAB1JtkyNgqY1NtoMbt

Comment: just pop the crlf onto this line:
    buildPW += digits.substring(index, index+1) + crlf;

Comment: This did not work.  I believe that this is one of the configurations I tried earlier.  Thanks for the reply though.